# My program won't run, because of an image I'm not using

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I've been using VB console for about 3 years, but I've just started with windows forms today. I made a picture box and put an image in there, but then deleted it from my program as well as from where it was originally stored. Now my program won't run, because it can't find the image and I don't know how to stop it from looking for the image. It's nowhere in the code where I can find it.
Here's the error message

> Error 2   Invalid Resx file. Could not find file
>   'C:\Users\Knowhow\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\monopoly
>   form\monopoly form\Resources\blank - Copy1.png'. Line 123, position
>   5.    C:\Users\Knowhow\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\monopoly form\monopoly form\My Project\Resources.resx    123 5   monopoly form

Comment: If you've just started today then why not abandon the application and start over? Otherwise, if you want to continue, you might need to go to the Project Properties and delete the image from Resources. Or use Find in Files.

Comment: Remove the resource from your project properties (at the bottom of the Project menu - choose Resources in the left pane of the resulting window). The error message tells you it's in `Resources.resx`.

Comment: Or remove it directly from the resx. ..